# Using IVY framework i am getting-------ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multiclass and multilabel-indicator targets

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to implement a Ivy framework for modifying the model using the kdd
[dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/hassan06/nslkdd)
Here is the code

```
import ivy; ivy.set_backend("jax")
import jax; jax.config.update("jax_enable_x64", True)
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import ivy.functional.frontends.xgboost as xgb_frontend
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from timeit import timeit
import xgboost as xgb
import pandas as pd
import functools
import ipytest; ipytest.autoconfig()
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook as tqdm
ivy.set_soft_device_mode(True)
def load_data(path):
    from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

    data = pd.read_csv(path, delimiter=",")
    columns = (['duration','protocol_type','service','flag','src_bytes','dst_bytes','land','wrong_fragment','urgent','hot','num_failed_logins','logged_in','num_compromised','root_shell','su_attempted'
    ,'num_root','num_file_creations','num_shells','num_access_files','num_outbound_cmds','is_host_login','is_guest_login','count','srv_count','serror_rate','srv_serror_rate','rerror_rate','srv_rerror_rate','same_srv_rate','diff_srv_rate'
    ,'srv_diff_host_rate','dst_host_count','dst_host_srv_count','dst_host_same_srv_rate','dst_host_diff_srv_rate','dst_host_same_src_port_rate','dst_host_srv_diff_host_rate','dst_host_serror_rate',
    'dst_host_srv_serror_rate','dst_host_rerror_rate','dst_host_srv_rerror_rate','attack','level'])
    data.columns = columns
    data = data.drop('level', axis=1)
    le = LabelEncoder()
    data['protocol_type'] = le.fit_transform(data['protocol_type'])
    data['service'] = le.fit_transform(data['service'])
    data['flag'] = le.fit_transform(data['flag'])
    data['attack'] = le.fit_transform(data['attack'])
    X = data.drop(['attack'], axis=1)
    y = data['attack']

    sc = StandardScaler()
    X = sc.fit_transform(data)
    return X, y

def prepare_data(arrays):
    if isinstance(arrays, tuple):
        arrays = list(arrays)

    for i in range(len(arrays)):
        if len(arrays[i].shape) == 1:
            arrays[i] = ivy.expand_dims(arrays[i], axis=1).astype(ivy.float32)
        else:
            arrays[i] = ivy.array(arrays[i], dtype=ivy.float32)
    return arrays
```

Below is the code for splitting and finding the accuracy and classification report;
I am getting this error on the last line:

```
Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multiclass and multilabel-indicator targets
```

what's wrong on it?

```
X, y = prepare_data(load_data("/content/data/KDDTrain+.txt"))
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=15)

params = {
    "objective": "multi:softmax",
    "booster": "gblinear",
    "n_estimators": 100,
    "learning_rate": 0.1,
    "reg_lambda": 0.1,
    "reg_alpha": 0.1,
    "base_margin": None
}

xgb_cls = xgb.XGBClassifier(**params)

ivy_cls = xgb_frontend.XGBClassifier(**params)
ivy_cls.compile(X_train, y_train)
ivy_cls.fit(X_train, y_train)

ivy_pred = ivy_cls.predict(X_test)

accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, ivy_pred) #Getting error for ths line
```

[image]

Comment: Please confirm that you are using `accuracy_score` from scikit-learn (it is not in your imports), or clarify otherwise. Also, please post a *sample* of your `ivy_pred` (these are the important details here, the rest is a largely irrelevant wall of code which we cannot reproduce).